# magento 2.1.1 - UPS shipping only populates in chrome browser - not fire fox or IE

Tags: shipping, ups

when I use IE or Firefox UPS shipping is not populating, Google Chrome its working like it suppose to, any idea how I can troubleshoot this? shopping cart page it populates in all browsers, but it wont populate in checkout page using IE or Firefox. when I refresh the page it shows for brief second and then it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the shipping address during the checkout? The shipping methods are not connected to the browsers particularities anyhow. 
If some shipping method is being hidden after the checkout page is reloaded - this shipping method might not be applicable to the selected address. The system loads shipping methods after the checkout page has been loaded. Upon this process, the system selects the shipping methods that are applicable to current shipping address and shows only these shipping methods